# How can I access the name of static member of a class in AS3 or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, static

I have the following class, I want to do what is in the comments
I know I can do it with conditionals.
I'd like to know if there is a way of doing that dinamicaly.

This code is in AS3, but I know maybe this is related to javascript because AS3 is based on 
ECMAScript

```
public class ClientStatus 
{
    public static const INVITED:int = 0;
    public static const VIP:int = 1;
    public static const MASTER:int = 2;
    public static const GRAND_MASTER:int = 3;
    public static const IMORTAL:int = 4;
    public static const GOD:int = 5;

    public static function getName(status:int):String
    {
        // to get the name related to int value
        // ex: if status equals to 3 return "GRAND_MASTER"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`describeType`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) you can get the names of all constants in `ClientStatus`. You can then loop over that list and build a dictionary, something like this:

```
// might have some errors, doing it from my head

private var dic:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

...

var desc:??? = describeType(ClientStatus);
...
for each (var constName:String in constNames) {
    dic[ClientStatus[constName]] = constName;
}

...

public static function getName(status:int):String {
        return dic[status];
}
```

Comment: what's the advantage of using describeType over creating the dictionary manually?

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns That you don't have to write (and maintain!) the same list of names and values twice (once in reverse). Of course, that may still be the most practical course, since the dynamic code, especially the parsing of `describeType`'s return value, can be large as well. Unless of course you make that its own function.

Comment: Will describeType get statics?  I thought that it would only get type data for an instance of the Class. Since statics belong to the Class definition and not any one instance, I would be skeptical about whether this would work. BTW, describeType returns xml.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship `describeType` describes, well, a type, so it should (or at least can also) be invoked on classes instead of instances. In that case it will, AFAIK, give information about static members.

Comment: Static members are not part of the data type.  If you create an instance of that type, those variables will not be accessible to it. So if describeType DOES pick up static members, it should be renamed--it's doing something other than what the name says.

Comment: @Amy Blankenship: which solution would you suggest, aside from the ones posted?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have an array of status strings: you pass the index number to the method and you get the status string. Other useful structures could be Object and Dictionary.